# Force html table into single stacked column using only css and no javascript

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a html template that wraps a table that is used to lay out a form. I have full control over the html that wraps the table not the table itself. The table is injected into my template before it's sent to the client. I have no control over this whatsoever. The only thing I do have control over is the html that wraps the table and any CSS.

The table is a two column table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is column 1</td>
    <td>this is column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

-------------------------------------------------
|Column 1                   |Column 2           |
-------------------------------------------------
|this is column 1           |this is  column 2  |
-------------------------------------------------
```

However I would prefer if we could show it as one stacked column.

```
----------------------------
|Column 1                   |
-----------------------------
|this is column 1           |
-----------------------------
|Column 2                   |
-----------------------------
| this is column 2          |
-----------------------------
```

Is there a way to achieve this using only CSS, no Javascript?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried before?

Comment: Wrap it in a div instead of table if you can change the wrapping html - much more simple and solid than using a table for this.

Comment: @KJF as easwee suggests using div will be better than table.

Comment: As I mentioned. I don't have the option of changing the table. The table is injected into my html template before being displayed to the client. I have no control over this. All I have control over is the html that wraps the table and any css.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not going to be able to force a table to display like this without some nasty hacks. You're going to have to change the markup. But as you say you have no way of doing this, maybe you can change which table element the information gets sent to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is not *reasonably* possible without changing the markup. Tables in HTML are structured as *rows*, not as *columns*. In the example you give **you're re-ordering the content**:

**Original order:**
`Column 1 -> Column 2 -> this-is-col-1 -> this-is-col-2`

**New ordering:**
`Column 1 -> this-is-col-1 -> Column 2 -> this-is-col-2`

Why did I say "not *reasonably* possible"? Well, with absolute positioning and similar techniques you may be able to hack the layout you want together - but there's a world of CSS-hurt waiting as I don't expect that approach to play nice in a real page.

---

Additional note: To add to the "re-ordering" problem, something that may be a little easier to accomplish would be this layout, where the order stays the same:

```
----------------------------
|Column 1                   |
-----------------------------
|Column 2                   |
-----------------------------
|this is column 1           |
-----------------------------
| this is column 2          |
-----------------------------
```

But that's obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 24):

Try adding this to you CSS:

```
td {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: While this is a clean solution IE will fail to display it.

Comment: Good for me. We don't really care for IE in our backend admin tool. And markup is hard to change as it is produced by complex library.

Comment: this also alternates the rows not stacks them like columns

Answer (score 5):

I was confronted with a similar problem recently & seem to have found a good solution. Tables have a bad rap due to frequent mis-use, but are indeed the leanest option when needing to display a grid of *data* in a variable width viewport.

The answer to the original question is still **no**. In order to solve this problem without JavaScript, one *must* be able to edit the table markup.

Tables can look... okay... when stretched wide, but look just terrible when squished. "Responsive" tables are possible only by adding contextual markup to each cell (e.g. `span.label` & `span.data` elements). We can easily hide this new superfluous output by default & only show it when in a responsive view state.

```css
table.responsive td .label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Foo</th>
            <th>Column Bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label">Column Foo</span><span class="data">Baz</span></td>
            <td><span class="label">Column Bar</span><span class="data">Qux</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When in a responsive view state, hide the `thead` element & show the `.label` elements.

```css
table.responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
table.responsive td .label {
  display: none;
}

table.responsive th {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

table.second {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  table.responsive thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table.responsive tbody th,
  table.responsive tbody td {
    display: block;
  }

  table.responsive td span {
    display: block;
  }
  table.responsive td .label {
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

I've created a [repo](https://github.com/yesnoio/responsive-table) which covers the solution in greater detail. Click [here](https://yesnoio.github.io/responsive-table/success.html) to see it work.

Answer (score 3):

Simply; No. You cannot turn a row turn a 2-column table into a 1-column table without some JavaScript. 
    Either tell the coders of the table to create the table that way, or simply use JavaScript to re-structure the table.

Comment: Not to mention poor coding anyway if they used a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar by using `display:block;`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R53KH/

Answer (score 0):

only solution I can think of is, changing your Markup. I would change it in such a way to take one column and write it as an row in markup. Here is an fiddle I have created : http://jsfiddle.net/MHsxU/

Answer (score 0):

**Still having issues and in Chrome?**
For those still having issues (like me) check you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the head of your document. If you don't Chrome seems to totally ignore anything you add and keep `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's incredibly easy (and can be done with 2 lines of css):  Make your td width 100% and set overflow:auto.  Your second column will automatically wrap around.