# How to do a wrap with a table cell according the window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a web project with Bootstrap 4 which compatible with smartphones. There are tables I need to do is:
1. When the window width get smaller, the table cell should get wrap down.
2. Same as in smartphones. If the smartphone screen has not enough space to show the page, the table cell should get wrap down.

This is what I want to get into:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_boxes
(But with table cell)

The sample code down there is  I try to do the thing above.

The solutions I've tried:
- `<div style="float:left;">` 
- `<table style="table-layout:fixed;">` with `<td style="word-wrap:break-word;">`

but these do not affect anything.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="a.jpg"></img></td>
      <td><img src="b.jpg"></img></td>
      <td><img src="c.jpg"></img></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: Thanks guys. I've solve this problem. I'm grateful to your answers and your help :)**

Comment: You can't do this (at least not easily/sensibly) using `<table>` - that's *exactly* what bootstrap grid was design for.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Then what can I deal with this for my situation?

Comment: As stated, use bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 2):

Using Media query, use `display:grid` when go below 768px... this will give you the effect that you're looking for

code **snippet** below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  tr {
    display: grid
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg"></img>
      </td>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg"></img>
      </td>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg"></img>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg"></img>
      </td>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg"></img>
      </td>
      <td><img class='img-fluid' src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg"></img>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, what a detail answer! This is at least what I try to achieve. I'll try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348574/10277087) answer, which in sort tells that table rows are designed to be in horizontal cells only, however you can achieve what you want IFF you are okay to use div or other elements instead. As you are using bootstrap 4, I will recommend you to [bootstrap-grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) or follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_examples10&stacked=h) example also given below:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">     
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
      <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here assuming total width given as 12 units, one can use col-(screen)-(n) as class names for columns where:

- col-(n) for width < 576px
- col-sm-(n) for width > 576px
- col-md-(n) for width > 768px
- col-lg-(n) for width > 992px
- col-xl-(n) for width > 1200px
- (n) can be any number from 1-12, however one should take care of the total sum not to exceed 12

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. When a remote website changes their url's or worse goes down then your answer will be useless.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your suggestion. This will be my reference :)

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaijens, I have updated my answer for the same, Although I believe the links are from official sites, and is less likely to go down. But I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.. it may work..

**css**

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        td {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The display attribute may be better if it's "grid". Thanks for your answer!