# How to make HTML table columns stack vertically within rows spanning the full width

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem regarding stacked displaying some HTML tables rows. The way I wanted all those to be displayed is like some sort of "card" with folding all columns into the rows, where the number of rows to be equal with the number of fields plus the same number of corresponding headers.

I'll give an example to better explain my requirement (this question was already asked before but wasn't quite satisfactory for me).

```css
 table {border:none }
    tbody { display:flex; }
    tbody > tr
    {
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     align-items:center;
     margin:5px;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }

    thead > tr
    {
     display:none;  
    }

    tbody > tr > td
    { 
     display:flex;
     justify-content:center;
     align-items:flex-start;
     padding:5px;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
     <thead><tr><th>FNAME</th><th>LNAME</th><th>AGE</th><th>ADDRSS</th><th>CITY</th> </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr><td>Smith</td><td>Milton</td><td>44</td><td>5th summer st, mntb</td><td>Portland</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Ken</td><td>Jackson</td><td>37</td><td>19th Penfield ave, brtcl</td><td>Kelowna</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Susan</td><td>Arkland</td><td>48</td><td>34th Mansfield st, sgtp</td><td>Raleigh</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Patsy</td><td>Brighton</td><td>35</td><td>12th Peel st, pnslv</td><td>Philadelphia</td></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

This table could approximately be represented like this:

|FNAME | LNAME  | AGE |        ADDRESS       |   CITY   |
|------|--------|-----|----------------------|----------|
|Smith |Milton  | 44  |  5th smmr st, mntb   | Portland |
| Ken  |Jackson | 37  |19th Pnfeld ave, brtcl| Kelowna  |
|Susan |Arkland | 48  |34th Mansfield st,sgtp| Raleigh  |
|Patsy |Brighton| 35  |12th Peel st, pnslv   |Phldlphia |
Fig. 1

And, through some CSS (or even Bootstrap or whatever) I'd need to display it as follows:

```
|================|    |================|
|      FNAME     |    |     FNAME      |    
|----------------|    |----------------|
|      Smith     |    |      Ken       |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|     LNAME      |    |     LNAME      |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|     Milton     |    |    Jackson     |
|----------------|    |----------------|    . . .  and so on
|       AGE      |    |      AGE       |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|       44       |    |      37        |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|     ADDRESS    |    |    ADDRESS     |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|5th smmr st,mntb|    | 9th Pnfeld ave,|
|----------------|    |----------------|
|      CITY      |    |      CITY      |
|----------------|    |----------------|
|    Portland    |    |    Kelowna     |
|================|    |================|
                  Fig.2
```

But I could only display it this way:

```
    |----------------|    
    |      Smith     |    
    |----------------|    
    |     Milton     |    
    |----------------|    
    |       44       |    
    |----------------|    
    |5th smmr st,mntb|    
    |----------------|    
    |    Portland    |    
    |----------------|
         Fig.3
```

But, as one could see, this display fails to intertwined the headers, so it is completely unsatisfactory.

So, to recap, I need that table from Fig.1 to be displayed like in the Fig. 2, NOT like in Fig. 3!

Comment: Table is probably not the right tool for the job here. Possibly look at CSS Grid instead

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a table like you had the given example. [image]

Make the table related your choice using `CSS` and `Jquery` with `Responsive` also `Sticky Table Header`, I hope it will be helpful to you.

given below Example. Thank you.

```css
table {border: none}
tbody {display: flex;}
tbody > tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
thead {display: none;}
tbody > tr > td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
tbody > tr > td::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:575.98px){
  table{width:80%;margin:0 auto}
  tbody {display: block;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>FNAME</th>
                      <th>LNAME</th>
                      <th>AGE</th>
                      <th>ADDRSS</th>
                      <th>CITY</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td data-title="FNAME">Smith</td>
                      <td data-title="LNAME">Milton</td>
                      <td data-title="AGE">44</td>
                      <td data-title="ADDRESS">5th summer st, mntb</td>
                      <td data-title="CITY">Portland</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td data-title="FNAME">Ken</td>
                      <td data-title="LNAME">Jackson</td>
                      <td data-title="AGE">37</td>
                      <td data-title="ADDRESS">19th Penfield ave, brtcl</td>
                      <td data-title="CITY">Kelowna</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td data-title="FNAME">Susan</td>
                      <td data-title="LNAME">Arkland</td>
                      <td data-title="AGE">48</td>
                      <td data-title="ADDRESS">34th Mansfield st, sgtp</td>
                      <td data-title="CITY">Raleigh</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td data-title="FNAME">Patsy</td>
                      <td data-title="LNAME">Brighton</td>
                      <td data-title="AGE">35</td>
                      <td data-title="ADDRESS">12th Peel st, pnslv</td>
                      <td data-title="CITY">Philadelphia</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```

In Responsive it will look like
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but wasn't that what I asked for. I don't want two columns data display but only one column display.
This whole column will be a particular row vertically transposed (or stacked) with header rows intertwined
with cell fields like this:
FNAME | Smith | LNAME | Milton | AGE | 44 | ADDRESS | 5th smmr st,mntb |CITY | Portland
exactly like in Fig. 2.
 Pay more attention through my requirements !
I could't find anywhere how to do it only with .css. But would be fine also with help of .js, bootstrap and the like.
 Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mcsS48, As per your requirement I tried to make it, please check. I hope it will be useful to you.
OR you can check the below link.
[https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCB91YEEPE9T]

Comment: No,definetely not this way. Your previous answer was much better. I did voted up your previous answer, as would be good for other's benefit.
 Anyway, if you can make it EXACTLY as my requirement (with .js) I'd appreciate it a great deal.
 I'll put in here one of the SO's link where this question has been asked before:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348294/force-html-table-into-single-stacked-column-using-only-css-and-no-javascript

but ain't nobody came up with a solution.
  Thank you again for your interest and (you guys) please keep searching for a solution.

Comment: Sure, i will try my best.